# Error in dimension processing , duplicates values for non key column

Tags: ssas

I am fairly new to analysis services.When I process AdventureWorks dimension DimCustomer(facing the issue for other dimensions like DimEmployee too) saying for attribute Firstname has duplicate values. It is not a key attribute in my dimension. Can anyone please help me if i am missing something here ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a Query text which SSAS sent to DB? You can find it under the error message when you expand the plus button at the left of your dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any trailing or leading spaces in the attribute or other special characters at the start or end? This can sometimes cause problems.

Also check you've got correctly defined attribute relationships between attributes.